# PHP on localhost losing session after redirect

Tags: php, mysql, apache, ubuntu, localhost

I've looked through the forum but actually nothing I've found works.

At start the environment: Ubuntu 23.10, Apache/2.4.57, PHP 8.2., MySQL, VsCode.
All php files are in the same directory. All happens on localhost.

How they work together.
Initially index.php checks the session status and redirects to login.php

```
if ( session_status() != PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE ) {
    header( 'Location: login.php' );
    exit();
```

Then in login.php 3 form fields are displayed with action processed by validatelogin.php.
In validatelogin.php

```
require_once( "db.php" );
if ( isset( $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] ) ) {
    if ( $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" ) {
        if ( empty( $_POST["login"] ) ) {
            header( 'Location: login.php?error=1' );
            exit();
        }
        if ( empty( $_POST["email"] ) and empty( $_POST["password"] ) ) {
            header( 'Location: login.php?error=2' );
            exit();
        }
        if ( empty( $_POST["email"] ) or empty( $_POST["password"] ) ) {
            header( 'Location: login.php?error=3' );
            exit();
        }
        if ( validateLogin( $_POST["email"], $_POST["password"] ) == false ) {
            header( 'Location: login.php?error=4' );
            exit();
        } else {
            session_name( $_POST['email'] );
            session_start();            
            $_SESSION["userid"] = $_POST["email"];
            $cookie_name = "last_login";
            $cookie_value = date( "d.m.Y H:i:s" );
            setcookie( $cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + ( 86400 * 420 ), "/" );
                        session_regenerate_id( true );
            header( "Location: index.php" );
            exit();
        }
    }
}
```

Db.php creates MySQL connection and contains a function to validate email/password.
Validation goes well and the code starts the session. I can't start it earlier because the requirement is to give it a name of email entered in login form.
In the debugger I can see session_status() being set to 2 after session_start().
But then after jumping back to index.php it gets reset to 1, so the code redirects back to login page.

File validatelogin.php is never required anywhere in the code. Is that an error? It's only entered in form's action.

Looking for solution I also tried session_write_close() but it didn't help. It resets the status to 1 immediately (probably expected behaviour).

Can it be something with server configuration or is the logic of the code wrong?

I have to mention that on the same machine Wordpress is installed. It has taken over the www sever configuration but I thought that results only with a different directory I have to put my files into.

Comment: At the very top of `index.php` do you start the session?  `session_start();` ?

Answer (score 0):

Zak is right. You must use session_start() to begin the session whether or not the user is logged in. Then instead of checking session_status(), you check your session variable $_SESSION["userid"] to check if the user is logged in. A session can exist for a guest user or a logged-in user, but only the logged-in user will have this session variable assigned.